# Adding ReactJS to a project without npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yii2

There is a ready-made project. Backend on Yii2, the frontend is written in it. Please tell me how to add a piece of the front on ReactJS to the finished page, so that, for example, in OpenServer, when you launch the site(my project), ReactJS is displayed correctly (without using npm in the console).
In other words, how to connect ReactJS to a project?

Comment: just build your project and use it in your back-end

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a build out of it using `npm run build`

and then from it you can link index.html

Comment: I did this, but react still doesn't show up on the index.html

Comment: The problem was that in index.html the src of the scripts started with /, but needed to be with ./  So when you open it index.html the page was empty.

Answer (score 0):

**Add React in One Minute**
In this section, we will show how to add a React component to an existing HTML page. You can follow along with your own website, or create an empty HTML file to practice.

There will be no complicated tools or install requirements — to complete this section, you only need an internet connection, and a minute of your time.

**Step 1: Add a DOM Container to the HTML**
First, open the HTML page you want to edit. Add an empty  tag to mark the spot where you want to display something with React. For example:

```
<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->

<div id="like_button_container"></div>

<!-- ... existing HTML ... -->
```

**Step 2: Add the Script Tags**
Next, add three  tags to the HTML page right before the closing  tag:

```
 <!-- ... other HTML ... -->

  <!-- Load React. -->
  <!-- Note: when deploying, replace "development.js" with "production.min.js". -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

  <!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="like_button.js"></script>

</body>
```

[enter link description here](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html)